# SKVideoNode won't play a AVPlayer loaded with local video

Tags: ios, video, sprite-kit

`SKVideoNode` seems to work fine when loaded using `videoNodeWithVideoFileNamed`, however when loaded using `videoNodeWithAVPlayer` it seems to just play the first (or one) frame of the video, and then nothing more. Known bug?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `play` on the SKVideoNode worked (**not** the AVPlayer!), even after loading it with AVPlayer. There is probably a good reason for that...

Comment: That's because, just like AVPlayer, SKVideoNode uses the AV Foundation but is its own player.

Comment: And the "You can use the AVPlayer object to control playback." means what? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKVideoNode/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKVideoNode/videoNodeWithAVPlayer:  What I am thinking is that the video is not ready to be played yet when I call play on the AVPlayer. SKVideoNode probably does not start to actually play the video until it actually can, I assume SKVideoNode takes care of all those small details like waiting for videos to load.